# how can i sort linearlayout data by name and type in android?

Tags: android

LinearLayout lin2 = new LinearLayout(this);
            lin2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

```
        LinearLayout lin3 = new LinearLayout(this);
        lin3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);


        mapfeautre.put("name",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue());
        TextView txtfeaturename = new TextView(this);
        txtfeaturename.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        txtfeaturename.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);
        String strtxtfeaturename =mapfeautre.put("name",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue());
        txtfeaturename.setText(strtxtfeaturename);
        lin3.addView(txtfeaturename);


        mapfeautre.put("distance",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("distance").getNodeValue());
        TextView txtfeaturedistance = new TextView(this);
        txtfeaturedistance.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        txtfeaturedistance.setPadding(90, 0, 0, 0);
        String strtxtfeaturedistance =mapfeautre.put("distance",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("distance").getNodeValue());
        txtfeaturedistance.setText(strtxtfeaturedistance+"ml");
        lin3.addView(txtfeaturedistance);

        lin2.addView(lin3);

        //mainlinear.addView(lin2);

        LinearLayout linsecond = new LinearLayout(this);
        linsecond.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        mapfeautre.put("venuetype",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("venuetype").getNodeValue());
        TextView txtfeaturevenuetype = new TextView(this);
        txtfeaturevenuetype.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        String strtxtfeaturevenuetype =mapfeautre.put("venuetype",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("venuetype").getNodeValue());
        txtfeaturevenuetype.setText(strtxtfeaturevenuetype+"-");
        linsecond.addView(txtfeaturevenuetype);

        mapfeautre.put("othervenuetype",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("othervenuetype").getNodeValue());
        TextView txtfeatureothervenuetype = new TextView(this);
        txtfeatureothervenuetype.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        String strtxtfeatureothervenuetype =mapfeautre.put("othervenuetype",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("othervenuetype").getNodeValue());
        txtfeatureothervenuetype.setText(strtxtfeatureothervenuetype);
        linsecond.addView(txtfeatureothervenuetype);

        mapfeautre.put("phonenumber",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("phonenumber").getNodeValue());
        TextView txtfeaturephonenumber = new TextView(this);
        txtfeaturephonenumber.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        String strtxtfeaturephonenumber =mapfeautre.put("phonenumber",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("phonenumber").getNodeValue());
        txtfeaturephonenumber.setText(strtxtfeaturephonenumber);
        linsecond.addView(txtfeaturephonenumber);
        lin2.addView(linsecond);
        //TextView txtaddress = new TextView(this);

        LinearLayout linthy = new LinearLayout(this);
        linthy.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        mapfeautre.put("address",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("address").getNodeValue());
        TextView txtfeatureaddress = new TextView(this);
        txtfeatureaddress.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        String strtxtfeatureaddress =mapfeautre.put("address",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("address").getNodeValue());
        txtfeatureaddress.setText(strtxtfeatureaddress+",");
        linthy.addView(txtfeatureaddress);          
        //lin2.addView(linsecond);
        //mainlinear.addView(lin2);
        //lin.addView(mainlinear);





        mapfeautre.put("zip",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("zip").getNodeValue());
        TextView txtfeaturezip = new TextView(this);
        txtfeaturezip.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        String strtxtfeaturezip =mapfeautre.put("zip",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("zip").getNodeValue());
        txtfeaturezip.setText(strtxtfeaturezip);
        linthy.addView(txtfeaturezip);  
        lin2.addView(linthy);

        mainlinear.addView(lin2);
        linhh.addView(mainlinear);
        linm.addView(linhh);



        //dataListfeture.add(mapfeautre);
        dataListfeture.add(j, mapfeautre);
        mylistfeature.add(j,mapfeautre);.
```

guys help me how can i sort my data in linear layout by name and type.

Answer (score 0):

I think there it is not possible to to sort a LinearLayout directly.

We have sort the Sting and then give it to LinearLayout in sorted order.

To sort the String following code is the easy solution.

```
Map<String, String>  sortedMap1;

sortedMap1=new TreeMap<String, String>(StringArray);
```

Comment: hello dude i understand what u say but if possible than give me one example demo